# delete method in junit test with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm making junit test for spring mvc project, I can make test method for get and post methods like the following example for get method,now I need to make test for delete method put I got this error

(The method DELETE(String, Long) is undefined for the type myclassTest)

this tutorial use delete with no error

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-rest-api-part-one/

```
   @Test
   public void testGetOne() throws Exception {
   ResultActions perform =  mockMvc.perform(get(
                MachineWebservice.URL+"/{id}",1)
        );
   perform.andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())             
        ;
  }
```

Comment: the previous code works well now I need to test delete method but got (The method DELETE(String, Long) is undefined for the type myclassTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply haven't statically imported the member (the `static` `delete` method declared within `MockMvcRequestBuilders`). Because of this, the compiler thinks that the method should exist in the class it's used in, `myclassTest`, which obviously isn't the case.

Add the appropriate `import` statement to your test class

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
```

Comment: No other than the `MockMvcRequestBuilders#get` method is working for me, e.g. `post` or `delete`. Any hint?

Comment: In the import statement "server" should be "servlet".

Comment: After reading a few answers in different threads, finally i have to admit that the solution was at hand all from the beginning... thanks!